# How to initialize ModalViewController in SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I am trying to display a ModalViewController on top of my root view controller as follows:

```
UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
ModalViewController *modal = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
[vc presentViewController:modal animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And in my ModalViewController, viewDidLoad is defined as :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene *endGameScene = [[EndGameScene alloc] 
                             initWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    endGameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:endGameScene];
}
```

When I run my code I get this error:

```
[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

It seems that skView is not recognized as SKView. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the View of your ModalViewController is no SKView. You have to create one and add it to the ModalViewControllerView:

```
SKView * skView = [[SKView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame]; 
[self.view addSubview:skView];
```